# Docker DNS settings

Tags: linux, networking, docker, dns, docker-network

I try create docker container with custom network and dos settings.

> docker network create --driver=bridge --opt "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade"="true" --opt "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc"="true" --opt="com.docker.network.driver.mtu"="1500" --opt="com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="0.0.0.0"  net

--

> docker run --dns 10.0.0.2 --network=net busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
>
> > nameserver 127.0.0.11
> >     options ndots:0

Else if I use standard network all work fine

> docker run --dns 10.0.0.2 --network=bridge busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
>
> > nameserver 10.0.0.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Docker 1.10, DNS is managed differently for user-defined networks.  DNS for the default bridge network is unchanged for backwards compatibility.  In a user-defined network, docker daemon uses the embedded DNS server.  According to the documentation found here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/

```
--dns=[IP_ADDRESS...]   The IP addresses passed via the --dns option is used by the embedded 
                        DNS server to forward the DNS query if embedded DNS server is unable
                        to resolve a name resolution request from the containers. These 
                        --dns IP addresses are managed by the embedded DNS server and will not
                        be updated in the container’s /etc/resolv.conf file.
```

So, the DNS nameserver will be used, it just is not visible in the container's /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: Using this option maps the nameserver's ip into the container's /etc/resolv.conf file. It is visible in there.

Comment: As alternative you can use [this solution](https://github.com/mageddo/dns-proxy-server/), it's a DNS server that solves containers hostnames, solves addresses from internet as well

Comment: how would i add this in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Updated link to correct section of the documentation is https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services