# Docker Container not use host DNS

Tags: docker, dns

i'm used custom docker network named "backend-network"

```
[root@localhost docker]# docker inspect backend-network
    {
        "Name": "backend-network",
        "Id": "18180c0c1ef14460a25b66b7fb971e090f7bb85f549921704d11937af70766c7",
        "Created": "2018-08-07T12:36:02.4175991+09:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "531c1ecbe993ee13e632fbd9697b392ee989d756ff60c07eae96a700901aaa01": {
                "Name": "splash",
                "EndpointID": "c9e4e7ec319ecf9cdcbb9ca50170efb63c4fca33bcbbabb584c4a4e41576b15d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c6a5aa827e901b6b6d7b35d4a8be5a5b2fc73f1a7a385416ce200e847d400b21": {
                "Name": "flask",
                "EndpointID": "5d5abb3bc964d251379a7f6a84cb5b5d9bddac9b778f2222d52aba657b28dd34",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "da839143fb58d738e38922c669efa332c545fee4dd0a5b733583ed7b8df60875": {
                "Name": "django",
                "EndpointID": "f046e9cc93f895b12ce1c4de983fbe0e54a3904460c04db3ba238ba84ba82327",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "fc9e6ef183c81a3fe7dd29ecb5c17c0dc27fb803ef8e214d4f344a2b3407ec54": {
                "Name": "mongo",
                "EndpointID": "ab94182f4b175f105ab01ccbbc43b7dad37cf5506eee831168fd5bd9094ccde8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
```

But each Container not used host DNS.

host DNS is.

```
[root@localhost docker]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.88.1
```

and container DNS is

```
(django) root@da839143fb58:/opt/django_backend/scrapy_app# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

i added

> nameserver 192.168.88.1

container's resolv.conf, and it works but request too long.

I think first search in

> nameserver 127.0.0.11

and search

> nameserver 192.168.88.1

how can i set docker-network to host dns?

remove

> nameserver 127.0.0.11

then don't communicate other container by name. like

```
 (django) root@da839143fb58:/opt/django_backend/scrapy_app# ping splash
 ping: splash: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers are resolving DNS requests through embedded DNS server (this is the IP you are seeing in the container's `/etc/resolv.conf` – see bottom note in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)). Depending on your configuration the embedded DNS server forwards the query to your host (default) or another DNS-server. You can pass a custom DNS server with the `--dns`- flag.

Please find more information about that in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/).

Comment: "In the absence of the --dns=IP_ADDRESS..., --dns-search=DOMAIN..., or --dns-opt=OPTION... options, Docker uses the /etc/resolv.conf of the host machine (where the docker daemon runs)" in documentation..                                                                     why don't use host machine /etc/resolv.conf (my case) ?? i don't set dns option to containers

Comment: When you use a custom network, the resolving is done through the docker daemon. The requests are actually forwarded to the DNS servers configured in your host's `resolv.conf`. But through a single DNS server (the embedded one of docker).

Comment: You can find more information in this related question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483053/docker-dns-settings?rq=1)

Comment: When I'm using --dns 192.168.88.1 then also not working. but change 8.8.8.8 then work.. I don't now why container could not use hosts dns.